# Обнуление переменной setInterval

Tags: javascript

Может кто-то пожалуйста объяснить принцип работы setInterval при сохранении этого "интервала" в переменную.
При первом старте интервала в переменную заносится значение "2". После остановки интервала, я переменную обнуляю, но при повторном старте значение переменной уже будет = "3". С чем это связано?

```js
var interval = 0;
but1.onclick = () => {
  interval = setInterval( () => console.log(interval), 100)
}
but2.onclick = () => {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = 0;
  console.log(interval + '// обнулился');

}
```

```html
<button id = 'but1'>start</button>
<button id = 'but2'>end</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Встроенный метод [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) возвращает числовой идентификатор созданного таймера, передав который в [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) вы можете этот таймер остановить преждевременно.

Обнулять эту переменную нет необходимости, если следующий вызов `setInterval` её перезапишет.

Аналогично работают методы [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout)

Comment: То есть, получается при clearInterval таймер не удаляется, а просто останавливается и его идентификатор никак не удаляется, верно?

Comment: ну не принципиально, храните Вы его идентификатор или нет, после остановки, я не знаю специфицировано это или нет, можно считать это порядковым номером таймера, только остановленный таймер уже все равно никак не запустить, даже зная его идентификатор

Comment: можно уточнить, что встроенный в браузер метод возвращает числовой идентификатор. В других средах может быть другой результат